# Github hook for pull_request sent to AmazonSNS

Tags: github, amazon-web-services

I've seen (and tested) GitHub's integration with Amazon SNS.  But, there doesn't appear to be a way to specify what events you want to hook (at least in the UI).  Push works fine.  Is there a way to hook a pull request and have it push an event to an sns topic?

Note: if there is documentation for this, I have not be able to find it.  Please include a link with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, for future readers, I think I found my own answer.  I found the following:

```
 {
    "name": "amazonsns",
    "events": [
        "push"
    ],
    "supported_events": [
        "commit_comment",
        "create",
        "delete",
        "download",
        "follow",
        "fork",
        "fork_apply",
        "gist",
        "gollum",
        "issue_comment",
        "issues",
        "member",
        "public",
        "pull_request",
        "pull_request_review_comment",
        "push",
        "status",
        "team_add",
        "watch"
    ],
    "schema": [
        [
            "string",
            "aws_key"
        ],
        [
            "string",
            "aws_secret"
        ],
        [
            "string",
            "sns_topic"
        ],
        [
            "string",
            "sqs_queue"
        ],
        [
            "password",
            "aws_secret"
        ]
    ]

}
```

This was at: https://api.github.com/hooks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what this means? I'm trying to push a pull_request event to sns topic

Comment: same here, curious to as how you change the default ping @david-s

Comment: I answered below @dkulkarni if you're still haven't found out.

Comment: Thanks @BenFradet. I managed to change my strategy. Ended up using API gateway as a webhook that triggered a lambda. Worked out way simpler than an SNS based approach

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the OP's answer:

- you need to get the amazon sns integration hook id through [the list hooks endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#list-hooks) (`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/hooks`)
- once you have the corresponding id, you need to add/remove supported events through [the edit a hook endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#edit-a-hook) (`PATCH /repos/:owner/:repo/hooks/:id`)

I personally didn't know that integrations were treated as "usual" webhooks.